# Convergence of a sequence with consecutive terms getting closer in a compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let ($X,d$) be a compact metric space. Let {$x_n$} be a sequence in $X$ such that $d(x_{n+1},x_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. If set of limit points of the sequence is finite, then for any two limit points $a,b \in X$, show that  $d(a, b) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Note that my question is not just to prove that the sequence is convergent if number of limite points for the sequence is finite, but to prove the exact statement in the question. If I fix an $\epsilon > 0$, can I control the sequence to show that distance between any two limit points is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: This does not make sense. If $d(a_i,a_j) <\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ then $a_i=a_j$.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I have changed the question now. We have to infact prove that if the number of limit points is finite, then the sequence converges. One way to show the convergence of sequence is by proving the statement given in the question. I could not prove this specific statement. This is the reason why I have rephrased my question in the currrent form.